# Rails ActiveRecord - is there a way to perform operations on tables without an id?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a table with one row and two columns-

```
int 'version', datetime 'updated'
```

Is there a Rails ActiveRecord way to get and set the data in these columns?
There is no id column.

I'm using this table to track versions of queries of other tables. After each query of another table the version column is incremented and the updated column is set with current datetime.

Comment: My intent is to have this table work similar to how Rails tracks migration versions with the 'schema_info' table.

Comment: I have put up a blog on this topic: http://ho.race.hk/blog/?p=208

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing prevent you to use it in ActiveRecord without ID :

The migration contains :

```
create_table :posts, :id => false do |t|
  t.integer :version
  t.datetime :updated
end
```

Queries :

```
>> Post.create(:version => 1, :updated => Time.now)
=> #<Post version: 1, updated: "2009-05-05 19:24:31">
>> Post.all
=> [#<Post version: 1, updated: "2009-05-05 19:24:31">]
>> Post.all(:conditions => { :version => 1 })
=> [#<Post version: 1, updated: "2009-05-05 19:24:31">]
```

The log report these SQL requests :

```
CREATE TABLE "posts" ("version" integer, "updated" datetime) ;
INSERT INTO "posts" ("version", "updated") VALUES(1, '2009-05-05 19:24:31');
SELECT * FROM "posts" 
SELECT * FROM "posts" WHERE ("posts"."version" = 1)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I didn't know it worked like that.  Cool stuff.  Although, I would imagine an update or delete wouldn't work as expected since those operations depend on an existing primary key.

Comment: .all is an alias to .find(:all). Using most other parameters to .find will result in a error due to the lack of an id.

Answer (score 7):

In your model class, use `self.primary_key = "primary_key_column"` to specify the column to use as the primary key column. I guess that in your case you could use the version column.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing Rails works with, when no `id` column is present, is a `has_and_belongs_to_many` join table.

Otherwise you have to drop down to pure SQL, with something like:

```
SomeModel.connection.execute "select * from mytable"
```

---

Or if `version` is intended to be the primary key, use John's answer.