# Create an ActiveRecord database table with no :id column?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, activerecord

Is it possible for me to create and use a **database table** that contains no **:id** column in ActiveRecord, Ruby on Rails.

I don't merely want to ignore the **id column**, but I wish it to be absolutely non-existent.

```
Table Example

:key_column                         :value_column
0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661    0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661
4a8a08f09d37b73795649038408b5f33    0d61f8370cad1d412f80b84d143e1257
92eb5ffee6ae2fec3ad71c777531578f    9d5ed678fe57bcca610140957afab571
```

Any more info ( like an :id_column ) would break the whole feature.

How would I implement something like this in rails?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825489/rails-activerecord-is-there-a-way-to-perform-operations-on-tables-without-an-id/

Comment: You should ask those as separate questions.

Comment: removed the second part of the question. asked at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874755/ruby-on-rails-activerecord-storing-rows-ordered-and-accessing-with-binary-searc]

Answer (score 135, accepted):

yup, looks like this:

```
create_table :my_table, id: false do |t|
  t.string :key_column
  t.string :value_column
end
```

just make sure to include the

```
id: false
```

part.

Comment: is there any place i can config the default to not generate id?