# Tried to create table without id column but facing 'unique index' error from sqlite

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, rake

I followed the instruction on link below to "create table with no 'id' column", since i am using 'emp_id' instead. 
[Create an ActiveRecord database table with no :id column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874634/create-an-activerecord-database-table-with-no-id-column)

I am facing error "table users has no column named id: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX" from Sqlite. Just wondering if you could provide some suggestions to me.
Thank you so much for your kind input.

Below is the original migration file:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :users, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :emp_id
      t.string :name
      t.integer :dept_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

Below is the result after running "rake db:migrate"

```
-- add_index(:users, :id, {:unique=>true})
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
SQLite3::SQLException: table users has no column named id: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX       "index_users_on_id" ON "users" ("id")
```

Sincerely,
Kevin H

Comment: Looks like your migration is missing something (or you have another migration out there), look at the output -> -- add_index(:users, :id, {:unique=>true}), where is this add_index call happening?

Comment: Hi Mauricio Linhares, you are right. I found out that I have another migration file in the same directory with command "add_index :users, id, :unique => true". When I removed the extra migration file, the problem is solved. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord expects a primary key for all tables that back a model (not a relationship, like a HTBTM–join table). What you're trying to do appears to be STI (single-table inheritance), and it's supported in another fashion (see [Single Table Inheritance in The Rails 3 Way](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/ruby/9780132480345/advanced-active-record/ch09lev1sec5?reader=pf&readerfullscreen=&readerleftmenu=1#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTk3ODAxMzI0ODAzNDUvMjY5)).

Comment: Dear Coreyward, thank you for your feedback. I found out that the root cause is that I got another migration file in the same directory. I have resolved the issue based on suggestion by "Mauricio Linhares". Thank you for your input. You have a wonderful day :)