# rails import sql, column mismatch on id

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have a series of sql statements that I am reading into my db - specificially, I am seeding a table with cities and coordinates, but am a little confused as how to handle missing ID columns in sql dumps.

My migration to create the table:

```
class CreateCitiesExtended < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :cities_extended do |t|
      t.string :city
      t.string :state_code
      t.integer :zip
      t.float :latitude
      t.float :longitude
      t.string :county
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :cities_extended
  end
end
```

After running the migration:

```
sqlite> PRAGMA table_info(cities_extended)
0|id|INTEGER|1||1
1|city|varchar(255)|0||0
2|state_code|varchar(255)|0||0
3|zip|integer|0||0
4|latitude|float|0||0
5|longitude|float|0||0
6|county|varchar(255)|0||0
```

The sql file looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `cities_extended` VALUES ('Holtsville', 'NY', '00501', '40.8152', '-73.0455', 'Suffolk');
INSERT INTO `cities_extended` VALUES ('Holtsville', 'NY', '00544', '40.8152', '-73.0455', 'Suffolk');
INSERT INTO `cities_extended` VALUES ('Adjuntas', 'PR', '00601', '18.1788', '-66.7516', 'Adjuntas');
```

But when I attempt to read the .sql file into my sqlite table, I get a column mismatch error:

```
rails db
sqlite> .read ./db/data/cities_extended.sql

Error: near line 41780: table cities_extended has 7 columns but 6 values were supplied
Error: near line 41781: table cities_extended has 7 columns but 6 values were supplied
```

As you can see from the migrated table, an extra column called id was created by rails. This prevents the table from being seeded. What is the best way to satisfy the column requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do require the default id column, you can amend the INSERT sql to specify the columns used:

```
INSERT INTO `cities_extended` (city, state_code, zip, latitude, longtitude, county) VALUES ('Holtsville', 'NY', '00501', '40.8152', '-73.0455', 'Suffolk');
```

This should give you the normal auto-incremented id column as generated by the table.

Answer (score 0):

So i found a work around, but I'm not convinced its the best way:

```
class CreateCitiesExtended < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :cities_extended, :id => false do |t|
```

Setting :id => false allows me to bypass the requirements.

It works for my cause, but I'm not sure its the best way because there will not be any unique ID's on any of the records. I'll leave the question open in case someone knows of a better way?

source: [Create an ActiveRecord database table with no :id column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874634/create-an-activerecord-database-table-with-no-id-column)

Answer (score 0):

Add a migration to populate the data. In that migration, create your records.

```
class MigrateCities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    CitiesExtended.create(:city => "Holtsville", :state_code => "NY", :zip => "00501", rest of fields)
    rinse, repeat
  end
end
```

You will want to decide whether your Zip is really an integer or not. Zip+4 would indicate that you should use a string, not an integer.