# Scaffolding table obtained by many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have two models: **User** and **Club** and I have a many-to-may relationship like:

```
user has_and_belongs_to_many clubs
club has_and_belongs_to_many users
```

Now, I will have a third table with the result of this relationship:

**user_clubs(user_id, club_id)**

When generating scaffold, for example, **rails generate scaffold User name:string birth_date:date
gender:string login_id:integer**, how can I generate that relationship? In the same way?

Thank you

Comment: for those reading in the future consider using a has_many through relationship

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `generate migration`

```
rails g migration create_club_users user_id:integer club_id:integer
```

---

It will create the following migration:

```
class CreateClubUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :club_users do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :club_id
    end
  end
end
```

Then you should set `id` to `false` as in [Create an ActiveRecord database table with no :id column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874634/create-an-activerecord-database-table-with-no-id-column)

---

I suggest that you read [WHY YOU DON’T NEED HAS_AND_BELONGS_TO_MANY RELATIONSHIPS](https://flatironschool.com/blog/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many/).

Comment: You can do it just with `rails g migration CreateJoinTableUserClub user club`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
rails g migration CreateClubsUsersJoinTable club_id:integer user_id:integer
```

You should follow **alphabetical order of models** when creating **join table** of `has_and_belongs_to_many` association in rails

Please refer this link for further assistance

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many