# Rails: Create a no-id model using generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to use the `$ rails generate model` to explicitly not using the id since I want to create a joined table with foreign keys instead.

I am fully aware that we can do that by going to the migration table, as follow:

```
# Just an example to demonstrate <id: false>
create_table :my_table, id: false do |t|
  t.string :key_column
  t.string :value_column
end
```

*[StackOverflow Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874634/create-an-activerecord-database-table-with-no-id-column)*

But is there a way to do so using the generator? And yes, I've checked the help option:

`$ rails g model -h`

but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Do you need model or just  join migration?

Comment: if you just need a join table with no other things just create a join migration

Comment: `rails g migration CreateJoinTableUsersRoles user:references role:references`